# Timestamp Modification in SqlServer 2008

Tags: sql-server, datetime

In a table I have `claimId` and `paidDate`. For a given `paidDate` I have 20 `ClaimID`. `paidDate` datatype is datetime. So Business Needs paid date to be unique for all `ClaimID`. So how can I update uniquely timestamp part of `PaidDate` in sqlserver..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Robin...

```
declare @claimid int
declare cur CURSOR FOR
select claimid from dbo.claimsID order by claimid
begin
open cur
FETCH next FROM cur 
into @claimid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
begin
update dbo.claimsID set paiddate=getdate() where claimid=@claimid
waitfor delay '00:00:01'

FETCH next FROM cur 
into @claimid
end

CLOSE cur   
DEALLOCATE cur
end
```

Comment: This will replace the paidDate value with current date. If this is what OP wants, it works fine, I guess. Business-wise, I don't think it is what OP should want.

Answer (score 0):

Use default getdate() in the paiddate column

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, ClaimID, PaidDate)
```

This will keep paidDate value, but add minutes of the ID. 
If the ID's are very big, you might want to hand out a `ROW_NUMBER` and use that to add as minutes.

Answer (score 0):

@Robin

hold all the claimid in a cursor and update one by one  and after update statement keep WAITFOR '00:00:01'clause .... every record will get updated with a difference of 1 second...

Comment: Creative. I'd prefer my answer though, if only for performance.